# Pop To RootView Controller issue

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller

In my project I have some set of view controller added in a navigation controller like.

**UIViewController1,UIViewController2,UIViewController3,UIViewController4,UIViewController5**
consider `UIViewController1` is my root view controller of navigation controller. after the navigation reaches `UIViewContoller5` on button click I need to return back to my `UIViewController1`. So I'm writing following code.

```
 - (void)popToRootViewControllerAnimated
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",[self.navigationController viewControllers]);
        [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
```

In console it prints like

```
(
    "<UIViewController1: 0x8e3fcc0>",
    "<UIViewController2: 0x9a5d310>",
    "<UIViewController3: 0x9a67b00>",
    "<UIViewController4: 0x9162a00>",
    "<UIViewController5: 0x9a84380>"
)
```

But after it finishes execution my view stays at `UIViewController3`. If I print `[self.navigationController viewControllers]` in my `UIViewController3` it shows like,

```
(
        "<UIViewController1: 0x8e3fcc0>",
        "<UIViewController3: 0x9a67b00>",
    )
```

What I m missing. Thanks in advance. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Show the code..you are adding viewController to stack?

Comment: are you using the storyboard?

Comment: Try `[self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];`

Comment: As usual [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[[UIViewController2 alloc] init] animated:YES];

Comment: @Akhilrajtr tried all possible ways [self.navigationController popToViewController:[[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0] animated:NO];

Comment: can you show the code to push `UIViewController3`? is `UIViewController3` is in a separate `UINavigationcontroller`?

Comment: for push view controller..

YourViewController *yourVC=[[YourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:yourVC animated:YES];

and for pop view controller..

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

try this..

Comment: @Akhilrajtr see console result it is pushed in same viewController

Comment: @ Ashish Kakkad Tried it also but no use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
UIViewController *firstVc = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
[navCtrl setViewControllers:@[firstVc] animated:NO];
```

Comment: How do you alloc UINavigationController? And the way to push Vc3? From the Apple document, **The root view controller becomes the top view controller.** There should be only a root controller, so I can't explain why.

Comment: Interesting...  I'm curious as to what would happen if you did something like [navCtrl setViewControllers:@[firstVc, secondVc....] animated:NO];

Answer (score 1):

Try this hope this will solve your problem

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

this controller take you at zero(0) index of you all controllers.
Try this one

```
UIViewController *ctrl = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count -1];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:ctrl animated:YES];
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: can you change this [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:-2] And try once again.

Comment: [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:-2] For this also same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this.

```
 -(void)backButtonAction
{
   YourAppDelegate *app=(YourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

   for(UIViewController *vc in app.yourNavigationController.viewControllers)
       {
           if([vc isKindOfClass:[UIViewController1 class]])
           {
             [app.yourNavigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];  
           }
       }
}
```

Comment: Tried that too. Not woking.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works

```
  for(UIViewController *objUIViewController in [self.navigationController viewControllers])
    {
        if([objUIViewController isKindOfClass:[UIViewController1 class]])
        {
            [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:objUIViewController]animated:YES];
        }
    }
```